# `pypdf`'s `merge_scaled_page` leads to blank pages if content is complex

Tags: python, pdf, merge, pypdf

I am using a combination of `reportlab` and `pypdf` to add page numbers to a list of pdfs.

1. Firstly I use `pypdf` -  `PdfMerger` to concatenate many pdfs.
2. Then `reportlab` makes a pdf of numbered but otherwise blank pages
3. I then use `pypdf`- `merge_scaled_page` to combine the numbers to the concatenated pdf.

This third step is not reporting errors, but it is producing bad output intermittently.

Here is the business-part of the code

```
with open(tmp, "rb") as ftmp:
            number_pdf = PdfReader(ftmp)
            # iterate pages
            for p in range(n):
                page = reader.pages[p]
                number_layer = number_pdf.pages[p]
                page.merge_scaled_page(number_layer,scale=1.0,over=True)
                writer.add_page(page)
```

Now, 90% of the time this works fine.  But sometimes pages in the finished document come out blank.  It is not random: I can usually predict which pages will fail, namely the pages with complicated content.  For example, a microsoft word doc with many reviewing markups, or a combination of many detailed Excel charts on the one page.  Apart from this general feature, I cannot see any difference between the pages that work and the ones that don't.  I have tried variations on the `merge_scaled_page` to see if this would help, but it doesn't.

Currently my work-around is just to skip the step for `page.merge_scaled_page` if the page is complicated; but this is very manual and not satisfactory.

Any ideas?